# Nginx reverse proxy to wordpress in docker container through ecs

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to proxy_pass to an http Wordpress site that is set up in a docker container through an Amazon ecs instance. The client gets to the site through a test server we have set up (https://test.xxxxxxx.com). When a user goes to https://test.xxxxxxx.com, I want it to show https://test.xxxxxxx.com in the address bar, but bring up the page for my Wordpress site (http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 80).

I can get it to go to my Wordpress site, but it looks funny. I am getting a lot of mixed content errors because I'm trying to access http files via an https request. I understand what's happening, but I can't seem to fix it, even after trying all of the suggestions I could find online.

I have tried changing several settings in both the Nginx file in the sites-available folder and by changing settings in wp-config.php on my Wordpress site. Below is one thing I tried. Almost all the tutorials I found, and everything I tried, was a variation of this.

```
#Nginx file

server {
    listen 443;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

```
#wp-config.php

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = '1';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}

define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
```

What I would like to happen is that when a user enters https://test.xxxxxxx.com in the address bar, my Wordpress site loads with the proper theme and all my images, but https://test.xxxxxxx.com still shows in the address bar.

Comment: `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` should be set to `https://test.xxxxxxx.com`

Comment: I tried this, but when I go to that page it says that test.xxxxxxx.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

I wanna sugguest you use HA-Proxy reverse proxy in ECS.
I tried nginx reverse proxy, but failed. And success with HA-Proxy.
It is more simple than nginx configuration.

First, use "links" option of Docker and setting "environment variables" (eg. LINK_APP, LINK_PORT).

Second, fill this "environment variables" into haproxy.cfg.

Also, I recommend you use "dynamic port mapping" to ALB. it makes more flexible works.

taskdef.json :

```
# taskdef.json

{
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<APP_NAME>_ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "<APP_NAME>-rp",
        "image": "gnokoheat/ecs-reverse-proxy:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "memoryReservation": <MEMORY_RESV>,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 0,
            "containerPort": 80,
            "protocol": "tcp"
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          "<APP_NAME>"
        ],
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "LINK_PORT",
            "value": "<SERVICE_PORT>"
          },
          {
            "name": "LINK_APP",
            "value": "<APP_NAME>"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "<APP_NAME>",
        "image": "<IMAGE_NAME>",
        "essential": true,
        "memoryReservation": <MEMORY_RESV>,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "containerPort": <SERVICE_PORT>
          }
        ],
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "PORT",
            "value": "<SERVICE_PORT>"
          },
          {
            "name": "APP_NAME",
            "value": "<APP_NAME>"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
      "EC2"
    ],
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "family": "<APP_NAME>"
  }
```

haproxy.cfg :

```
# haproxy.cfg

global
    daemon
    pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000

frontend http
    bind *:80

    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]

    compression algo gzip
    compression type text/css text/javascript text/plain application/json application/xml

    default_backend app

backend app
    server static "${LINK_APP}":"${LINK_PORT}"
```

Dockerfile(haproxy) :

```
FROM haproxy:1.7
USER root
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

> See :
>
> Github : https://github.com/gnokoheat/ecs-reverse-proxy
>
> Docker image : gnokoheat/ecs-reverse-proxy:latest